# how to prevent too many postgres database locks

Tags: database, postgresql, locks

I do have a VM server running alfresco and postgres 9.3 database. My challenge is am hit by too many locks: this is the error message: POSTGRES_LOCKS CRITICAL: DB alf2 total locks: 3597 PROBLEM - Service Postgres DB Locks on Host Online Server is CRITICAL (Displayname: Postgres DB Locks).

Comment: Too many locks is an _application_ problem, not a Postgres problem. You should ask the Alfresco support.

Comment: I am running tomcat 7 and alfresco on a windows VM, anyone to assist please.

Comment: I here you but is there any way I can handle it.

Comment: There is the possibility that your PostgreSQL's configuration settings are not tuned well enough for your current demand, and the server is taking too long to process each query. Try to identify if any of your settings is too low (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-resource.html)